# CUDA toolkit compatibility

Tags: windows, windows-10, compatibility, cuda, windows-server-2019

I want to rent a server on Paperspace with GPU on a Windows instance. They offer only "Windows 10 running as Windows Server 2022" as OS, and the version of CUDA that I need (for Tensorflow) is 10.2 and It supports installation only on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019. So, is it possible to install CUDA as any of 2 mentioned types for my instance? Maybe they have compatibility by any chance?

UPD:
Available GPUs:
RTX4000
RTX5000
A4000
A5000
A6000

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, it’s impossible to say, as the version of CUDA that can be used, is hardware dependent

Comment: @Ramhound It's a question more about possibility to install CUDA 10.1 WS 2019 type/W10 type for WS2022. If there is a chance that I can install a newer version of CUDA, the variants of GPUs avaliable are now listed above.

Comment: CUDA is driver dependent, what versions of CUDA are supported, is hardware dependent. If there are CUDA drivers for Windows Server 2022 the you are fine. CUDA 10.3 should work just fine with Tensorflow

Comment: @Ramhound I just found out that the last supported version of CUDA for TensorflowGPU is 11.2. I guess that it won't work with any CUDA version higher than that because it isn't stated in the official documentation. Anyway, the last update of this version was in march 2021, and it doesn't have the Windows Server 2022 install option. So, the question remains

Comment: Have you tried? I would expect it to work fine but be limited to 10.2 functionality. Try it then update your question

Comment: I hope it will. Gonna try it